# Script to download a list of urls

Tags: shell, curl, wget

I have a shell script that download urls one by one and check for updates in static sites.Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

input="file.in"

while IFS= read -r line
do  
    # check if input line is a comment  
    case "$line" in \#*) continue ;; esac         

    line2="${line//\//\\}"

    if wget -q "$line" -O index.html > /dev/null; then
        if [ -f "$line2.html" ]; then
            cmp --silent "$line2".html index.html || echo "$line"
        else    
            echo "$line INIT" 
        fi          
    else
        echo "$line FAIL"
    fi  
    mv index.html "$line2".html  
done <"$input"
```

**file.in** is the list with urls. Example:

```
#List of addresses
http://www.google.com
http://www.spotify.com
http://www.flickr.com
http://www.soundcloud.com
https://www.facebook.com
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux
```

And i want to change the script to download all urls at once and save them with the same way with wget or curl. thanks!

Comment: IIRC `wget` alone already does [list downloads](https://askubuntu.com/a/103630/561230), and [retrieving only changed files](https://superuser.com/q/283481/582419).

Comment: Wait, so what is it exactly that you want to do? You want to download an updated copy of the webpage and store it? Is that it?

Comment: i want to read a website and download it. If i read it for first time i want to print the name of the site with INIT. If the site updated i want to print only the name of the site and if it cant read it i want to prin the name with FAIL. My code seems to work for doing this one by one i am not so sure. But i want to do this in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

A naive approach:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do  
    [[ "$line" == \#* ]] && continue
    (
        line2="${line//\//\\}"
        if wget -q "$line" -O index.html > /dev/null; then
            if [ -f "$line2.html" ]; then
                cmp --silent "$line2".html index.html || echo "$line"
            else    
                echo "$line INIT" 
            fi          
        else
            echo "$line FAIL"
        fi  
        mv index.html "$line2".html  
    ) &
done <"$input"
wait
echo "all done"
```

Comment: this does not seem to work because it overwrites the same file index.html